# How to find an Object on a arraylist by an embeddable id

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, arraylist

I have a many-to-many relationship between `Department` and `Employee` [image: Database Schema]

As a relational class that connect both `Employee` and `Department` classes I have a class called `DepartmentEmployee`, this class has an `@EmbeddableId` as the `id` which contains the primary keys from `Department` and `Employee`,

### DepartmentEmployee Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "dept_emp")
public class DepartmentEmployee {

        @EmbeddedId
        private DepartmentEmployeeId id;
    
        @JsonIgnore
        @MapsId("deptNo")
        @JoinColumn(name = "dept_no")
        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        private Department department;
    
        @JsonIgnore
        @MapsId("empNo")
        @JoinColumn(name = "emp_no")
        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        private Employee employee;
    
        @Column(name = "from_date")
        private LocalDate fromDate;
    
        @Column(name = "to_date")
        private LocalDate toDate;
    
        DepartmentEmployee() {
        }
    
        public DepartmentEmployee(Department department, Employee employee) {
            this.department = department;
            this.employee = employee;
            this.id = new DepartmentEmployeeId(department.getDeptNo(), employee.getEmpNo());
        }
    
        public DepartmentEmployeeId getId() {
            return id;
        }
    
        public void setId(DepartmentEmployeeId id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    
        public Employee getEmployee() {
            return employee;
        }
    
        public LocalDate getFromDate() {
            return fromDate;
        }
    
        public void setFromDate(LocalDate fromDate) {
            this.fromDate = fromDate;
        }
    
        public LocalDate getToDate() {
            return toDate;
        }
    
        public void setToDate(LocalDate toDate) {
            this.toDate = toDate;
        }
    }
```

### DepartmentEmployeeId class (The embedded class)

```
@Embeddable
public class DepartmentEmployeeId implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "dept_no")
    private String deptNo;

    @Column(name = "emp_no")
    private Long empNo;

    DepartmentEmployeeId() {
    }

    public DepartmentEmployeeId(String deptNo, Long empNo) {
        this.deptNo = deptNo;
        this.empNo = empNo;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;

        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
            return false;

        DepartmentEmployeeId that = (DepartmentEmployeeId) o;
        return Objects.equals(deptNo, that.deptNo) &&
                Objects.equals(empNo, that.empNo);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(deptNo, empNo);
    }
}
```

### Department Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "departments")
public class Department {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "dept_no")
    private String deptNo;

    @Column(name = "dept_name")
    private String deptName;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "department", orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<DepartmentEmployee> employees = new ArrayList<>();

    public String getDeptNo() {
        return deptNo;
    }

    public void setDeptNo(String deptNo) {
        this.deptNo = deptNo;
    }

    public String getDeptName() {
        return deptName;
    }

    public void setDeptName(String deptName) {
        this.deptName = deptName;
    }

    public void addEmployee(Employee employee, LocalDate fromDate) {
        DepartmentEmployee employeeToAdd = new DepartmentEmployee(this, employee);
        employeeToAdd.setFromDate(fromDate);
        employees.add(employeeToAdd);
    }

}
```

Now in `DepartmentEmployee` class I have two fields, `fromDate` and `toDate`, `fromDate` tells when an employee is added in a department, `toDate` is the date that tells when an employee is removed from the department, my problem is at the `delete` method which is supposed to find an `DepartmentEmployee` by `DepartmentEmployeeId` and set its `toDate` to whatever date i send it, but im not being able to make the method find an `DepartmentEmployee` by `DepartmentEmployeeId`

### The Method that i need to fix which is in the `Department` Class

```
public void deleteEmployee(Long empNo, LocalDate toDate) {
    DepartmentEmployeeId id = new DepartmentEmployeeId(deptNo, empNo);
    this.employees.stream().filter(employee -> id.equals(employee.getId())).findAny().orElseThrow(() -> new DepartmentNotFoundException(deptNo)).setToDate(toDate);
    
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work? What happens which you didn't expect to happen?

Comment: The method throws DepartmentNotFoundException because it cant find the DepartmentEmployee that im telling to find

Comment: The method seems ok to me, so maybe this is a data issue.

Comment: `id.equals(employee.getId())` looks weird! Because `id` is an instance of `DepartmentEmployeeId` and I assume that `employee.getId()` should return a `String`.

Comment: If the code is as you state it should work. So this might be a data issue or you are retrieving (for some reason) the wrong data to compare.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so i found the problem, it was not at the deleteEmployee() in department method but it was at deleteEmployeeFromDepartment() method in the service layer, i was using the wrong method to find the department, and for that it was returning an empty list of DepartmentEmployee

> From this:

```
@Override
    @Transactional
    public void deleteEmployeeFromDepartment(String deptNo, Long empNo, LocalDate toDate) {
        Department department = this.departmentRepository.findById(deptNo).orElseThrow(()-> new DepartmentNotFoundException(deptNo));
        department.deleteEmployee(empNo,toDate);
        this.departmentRepository.save(department);
    }
```

> To this:

```
@Override
    @Transactional
    public void deleteEmployeeFromDepartment(String deptNo, Long empNo, LocalDate toDate) {
        Department department = this.departmentRepository.findByIdWithEmployees(deptNo).orElseThrow(()-> new DepartmentNotFoundException(deptNo));
        department.deleteEmployee(empNo,toDate);
        this.departmentRepository.save(department);
    }
```